# Use the same object in different templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I've got one template that displays list of locations:

list_of_locations.html

```
{% for loc in loc_list %}
<p>
   Total desks: {{loc.total_desks}} 
</p>
<p>
   Free desks: {{loc.free_desks}}
</p>
<p>
   <a href="{% url 'cowork:offices:add' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Rent desk</a>
</p>
```

And I've got another template that displays form to add an office:

office_add.html:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'cowork:offices:add' %}">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_desks = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total desks')
    reserved_desks = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Reserved desks')


class Desk(models.Model):
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location, related_name='desks')
    rent_start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    rent_end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)Forms:

class OfficeCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Desk
        fields = ('location', 'rent_start_date', 'rent_end_date')
```

Views:

```
def search(request): 
    loc_list = Location.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'list_of_locations.html', 'loc_list': loc_list)

class OfficeAddView(UserMixin, views.LoginRequiredMixin, generic.FormView): 
    form_class = forms.OfficeCreationForm
    template_name = "cowork/offices/company/office_add.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cowork:offices:list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.company = self.user.companies.first()
        self.object.owner = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Now no matter which object is chosen by user in `list_of_locations.html`, the user is asked to choose the desk in `office_add.html`. I would like to change it so that when clicking on particular object in `list_of_locations.html`, the user is redirected to `office_add.html` but the desk.location is already chosen and when he/she save the form, desk.location will be the one that the user clicked in `list_of_locations.html`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last lines of `list_of_locations.html` to:

```
<a href="{% url 'cowork:offices:add' %}?location={{ loc.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Rent desk</ai>
```

Also I guess it would be nice if you disable the `location` field in `OfficeCreationForm` so the user can't change it.

Comment: Ok, I did it but when I add the office via form in `add_office.html` the location_id is not saved  - it's empty